# Strange noise coming from my bathroon outlet

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I turned on my bathroom light a couple nights ago & it sounded like morse code coming from the outlet.  I haven't heard it since that night.  My light switch is part of the double outlet.  Do you think this is indicating a problem with my wiring?  Thank you.

Comment: I'd wait for it to recur. Sometimes things like this don't recur. If it does, you'll need a cheap multimeter to use when you remove the cover and turn off the breaker to make sure there is no power in the box. Then disconnect and reconnect everything inside. Replace anything that's suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is indicating a problem. It's hard to tell what the issue might be, but electricity is silent when its working right.

BEFORE INVESTIGATING - turn off the breaker.

Things I would check AFTER turning off the breaker:

- take off the outlet cover and look for

  - burn marks
  - loose wires
  - cracked or worn insulation
  - cracked or worn parts on the outlet
  - signs of rodents
- take off the switch cover and look for the same things as the socket

The easy try-it-and-see repair is to replace the switch and outlet, this should cost maybe $10 and 30 minutes of work.

Do you know if you have aluminum or copper wiring in your home?

Is there a fan in this bathroom? Are you sure the noise was coming from the outlet and not a breeze blowing past the fan?